# $set operator interpreting array index as object index in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

MongoDB seems to interpret `$set` paths with numerical components as object keys rather than array indexes if the field has not already been created as an array.

```
> db.test.insert({_id: "one"});
> db.test.update({_id: "one"}, {$set: {"array.0.value": "cheese"}});
> db.find({_id: "one"})
{ "_id": "one", "array": { "0" : { "value" : "cheese" } }
```

I expected to get `"array": [{"value": "cheese"}]`, but instead it was initialized as an object with a key with the string "0".

I could get an array by initializing the whole array, like so:

```
> db.test.update({_id: "one"}, {$set: {"array": [{"value": "cheese"}]}});
```

... but this would clobber any existing properties and other array elements that might have been previously set.

Is there any way to convince `$set` that I want "array" to be an array type, with the following constraints:

1. I want to execute this in a single query, without looking up the record first.
2. I want to preserve any existing array entries and object values

In short, I want the behavior of `$set: {"array.0.value": ... }` if "array" had already been initialized as an array, without knowing whether or not it has.  Is this possible?

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/ ?

Comment: Or from the docs `db.products.update(
   { _id: 100 },
   { $set:
      {
        quantity: 500,
        details: { model: "14Q3", make: "xyz" },
        tags: [ "coats", "outerwear", "clothing" ]
      }
   }
)` so $set { arrayname : [ "value1", "value2" .... ]}

Comment: Yes @avrono, I've seen those.  Like I say in the question, I'm looking to set just one value on an existing array member (or add the array member if it doesn't yet exist), without clobbering other array entries. The array update operators you linked to don't do that, nor does the clobbering syntax you suggest (which is also in my question if you read it :)).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is possible without lookup. Perhaps you can change schema design, and try something like this:

```
db.test.insert({_id: "one"});
db.test.update({_id: "one"}, {$addToSet: {array: { $each:['cheese', 'ham'] }}});
db.test.findOne({_id:'one'});
// { "_id" : "one", "array" : [  "cheese",  "ham" ] }
```

Handling array elements (sub-documents in array) in MongoDb is pain. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243